# Where can I find the type definition of the Highcharts.AnnotationsOptions type?

Tags: highcharts

The Highcharts.AnnotationsOptions type is used in the addAnnotation method (and probably others). I have not been able to find the definition of this type. Is this defined somewhere in the api documentation?

[Ref. addAnnotation api documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addAnnotation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find `Highcharts.AnnotationsOptions` in 'configuration options' API section:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations